# c++ : Initialize constexpr std-2DArray programmatically

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++17

I am new to C++ and in the process of learning. I have a matrix deftype:

```
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, COL>, ROW>;
```

I can initialize a constexpr matrix "manually" as such

```
constexpr Matrix<int, 2,2> mat{ {
        {{ 1,2 }},
        {{ 3, 4 } }
}};
```

This is not feasible for large examples of ROW,COL. Instead i would like to initialize it "programmatically"(i.e. through a loop or similar) with a function `fill_entry` so that
`mat[i][j]` takes value `fill_entry(i,j)` and `fill_entry` is something like

```
 template<T>
constexpr T fill_entry(T This_object_has_type_T,int i , int j).
```

What is a correct way to do this? I use C++17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an immediately invoked lambda:

```
constexpr auto mat = []() {
    Matrix<int, 2, 2> result{};

    int value = 1;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < result[0].size(); ++j) {
            result[i][j] = value;
            ++value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}();
```

If you need to initialize multiple variables like this, you can make this into a function:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
constexpr Matrix<T, Rows, Cols> create_mat() {
    Matrix<T, Rows, Cols> result{};

    int value = 1;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < result[0].size(); ++j) {
            result[i][j] = static_cast<T>(value);
            ++value;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

and call it as `create_mat<int, 2, 2>()`.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution does not work with my compiler (MS visual studio), it gives me the error when caling create_mat that "constexpr function create_mat cannot result in a constant expression".

I found out that your solution works if i change from C++17 to the option "latest" which i guess means c++ 20. Which compiler/OS did you test yours on?

Comment: @Conformal You're right, it doesn't compile with C++17 (but does with C++20), the reason is `result` needs to be [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), so changing `result` to `result{}` should work (it works on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8nxKTe)).  I also fixed a few typos in my answer.